# Subset check with integer slices in Go

Tags: arrays, go, subset, slice

I am looking for a efficient way to check if a slice is a subset of another. I could simply iterate over them to check, but I feel there has to be a better way.

E.g.

> {1, 2, 3} is a subset of {1, 2, 3, 4}
>   {1, 2, 2} is NOT a subset of {1, 2, 3, 4}

What is the best way to do this efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want that for any type of values ?

Comment: Are the slices sorted?

Comment: Sort first, then iterate smaller slice, to binary search in larger one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most common way to solve a subset problem is via a map.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// subset returns true if the first array is completely
// contained in the second array. There must be at least
// the same number of duplicate values in second as there
// are in first.
func subset(first, second []int) bool {
    set := make(map[int]int)
    for _, value := range second {
        set[value] += 1
    }

    for _, value := range first {
        if count, found := set[value]; !found {
            return false
        } else if count < 1 {
            return false
        } else {
            set[value] = count - 1
        }
    }

    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(subset([]int{1, 2, 3}, []int{1, 2, 3, 4}))
    fmt.Println(subset([]int{1, 2, 2}, []int{1, 2, 3, 4}))
}
```

The ability to check duplicate values is relatively uncommon. The code above solves the problem as asked (see: http://play.golang.org/p/4_7Oh-fgDQ) though. If you plan on having duplicate values, you'll have to keep a count like the code above does. If there will not be duplicate values, you can solve the problem more compactly by using a boolean for the map value instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If your slices are sorted, this does the job.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Subset return whether a is a sublist of b. Both a and b must be (weakly) ascending.
func Subset(a, b []int) bool {
    for len(a) > 0 {
        switch {
        case len(b) == 0:
            return false
        case a[0] == b[0]:
            a = a[1:]
            b = b[1:]
        case a[0] < b[0]:
            return false
        case a[0] > b[0]:
            b = b[1:]
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    cases := []struct {
        a, b []int
        want bool
    }{
        {[]int{1, 2, 3}, []int{1, 2, 3, 4}, true},
        {[]int{1, 2, 2}, []int{1, 2, 3, 4}, false},
    }
    for _, c := range cases {
        if Subset(c.a, c.b) != c.want {
            fmt.Printf("Subset(%v, %v) = %v, want %v\n", c.a, c.b, Subset(c.a, c.b), c.want)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Algorithm to check if an array is a subset of another array in golang**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func compare(arr1 []int, arr2 []int) bool {
    for _, num1 := range arr2 {
        status := false
        for _, num2 := range arr1 {
            if num1 == num2 {
                status = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !status {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
func main() {
    arr1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    arr2 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    if compare(arr1, arr2) {
        fmt.Println("arr2 is subset of arr1")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("arr2 is not subset of arr1")
    }
}
```